# How to import QT c++ libraries in VS Code

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-code

I am trying to create a graphical application with QT, I would like to code it in VS Code.
I had installed QT 6.0.2 with the QT Creator installer.

To compile the C++, I use mingw810_64 which is located here : `C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_64/bin/g++.exe`

And so my libraries are located here :  `C:/Qt/6.0.2/mingw81_64/include/`

I have well modified the file `c_cpp_properties.json` :

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win64",
            "includePath": [
                "${default}",
                "C:/Qt/6.0.2/mingw81_64/include/"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.19041.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_64/bin/g++.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

And so here is the simple program I am trying to compile for now:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <QtGui>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QWidget window;
    
    window.resize(320, 240);
    window.show();
    window.setWindowTitle(
        QApplication::translate("toplevel", "Top-level widget"));
    return app.exec();
}
```

Unfortunately, it seems that VS Code can't find the QtGui library and so I can't even compile my application

I thank you for your help !

Comment: Your header problem is that c_cpp_properties.json is for intellisense only. tasks.json is where you set the include directory for building. With that said, Qt will be difficult to do in your tasks.json alone. It won't call moc, rcc, uic ... You probably want to use the CMake tools extension and CMake to support Qt.

Comment: Ok, I never used CMake, here is what I did :
https://pastebin.com/Sk6XT35B
QT is well found, the version is the right one, but I don't really know what to do

Comment: Your  CMake looks fine to me. There is a CMake tools Extension for VSCode

Comment: I downloaded it, I did "configure" but there are still problems in the cpp where it does not find the library. Moreover I have the message "Found Qt 6.0.2" when I "configure".

Comment: I have errors like "incomplete type not allowed"

Comment: So I found, I had forgotten to include ```QApplication``` and ```QWidget```. Now I can compile my project but when I run the .exe, there is an error telling me that some dlls are missing (those of ```Qt6Core``` and ```Qt6Widdgets```

Comment: You can fix that by either setting your system `PATH` environment variable to contain the location of the dlls or putting the dlls in the same folder as the executable. You may also be able to modify your `launch.json` to set the `PATH` environment variable for debugging there.

Comment: It Works !!! Is it possible to add to the build the dll to transport the build to other devices?

Comment: I have CMake create me a NSIS based install package but this can also be a solution [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html)

Comment: Related to CPack / NSIS: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39260000/how-to-idiomatically-package-dependencies-for-a-qt-application-using-cpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39260000/how-to-idiomatically-package-dependencies-for-a-qt-application-using-cpack)

Comment: @LolixDudu you can use windeployqt to copy all the necesary dlls into your programs folder just do on cmd promt ```windeployqt "path\tofolder\"``` , remember to be inside your qt mingw folder or it wont work, also can you show whats in your task.json? i cant link my qt librarys either